# how to fix warnings i18n spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

```
rails g spree_i18n:install
```

trace :

```
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spree_core-4.2.0.beta/lib/spree/i18n.rb:18: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.3.2/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb:60: warning: The called method `translate' is defined here
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/friendly_id-globalize-1.0.0.alpha3/lib/friendly_id/history.rb:73: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1370: warning: The called method `has_many' is defined here
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/awesome_nested_set-3.2.1/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:105: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1657: warning: The called method `belongs_to' is defined here
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/awesome_nested_set-3.2.1/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:90: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1370: warning: The called method `has_many' is defined here
         run  bundle exec rake db:migrate from "."
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spree_core-4.2.0.beta/lib/spree/i18n.rb:18: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.3.2/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb:60: warning: The called method `translate' is defined here
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/friendly_id-globalize-1.0.0.alpha3/lib/friendly_id/history.rb:73: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1370: warning: The called method `has_many' is defined here
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/awesome_nested_set-3.2.1/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:105: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1657: warning: The called method `belongs_to' is defined here
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/awesome_nested_set-3.2.1/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:90: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1370: warning: The called method `has_many' is defined her
```

~/../i18.rb

```
def translate(*args)
      @virtual_path = virtual_path

      options = args.extract_options!
      options[:scope] = [*options[:scope]].unshift(:spree)
      args << options
      super(*args)  #line 18 WARNING
    end
```

I tried to change it ****args** , but then i get

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

in this

```
only_integer: true, message: Spree.t('validation.must_be_int')
```

spree 4.2.0 beta
ruby 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Please update to stable 4.2.0, this will fix those issues.

```
bundle update spree
```